# Should my internal MVC/MVVM application use Web Services for Persistence?

Tags: mvc, web-services, mvvm, persistence

Just talking about internal applications or intranet web apps... At some companies I've seen their business-logic piece (Model in MVC/VM in MVVM) on one (or both) sides of a Web Service.  And on the other side of the web service is the Persistence.

```
MVC/MVVM > Service Layer > Persistence
```

This is only for intranet/internal application customers, and both the web or app code, and the persistence (usually ORM) dlls both sit on the same server, or even in the same folder.

I'm used to seeing internal apps and intranet websites that reference a business-layer... then that business-layer connects to persistence.  So the app itself is persistence-ignorant.

But with my own apps, if something needed to be exposed externally, that something is opened up via a web service.  But otherwise, everything stays internal.

Is there a reason for why I've seen a couple different companies do this?  They didn't seem to know the answer themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to think that's a bit silly. More formally, it's an example of what I would call "speculative generality".

The counterargument would be that the architecture you describe allows for other sorts of clients to be easily plugged into the same system with less effort, and that one never really knows what sort of new direction the project might take. (Realistically, though, sometimes these things *can* be known to a very great extent. Pretending everything's an unknown and requires generalization can be a very bad way to work, in my experience.)

I suppose that the deciding factor is how much effort the team thinks it will take to use Web Services. Superficially, it doesn't seem like the sort of thing that would require too much extra work. However, debugging and configuration implications must be considered (as opposed to just the code itself), and that's where I think that the Web Services approach probably damages the developer experience.

Comment: Thank you for that answer.  I agree with it and wonder how many others agree with it.  I like that you tried to make a counter argument, but it obviously isn't a very good one.  I haven't yet spoken to anybody with a good argument for this idea, but that's why I ask a community, to see if one exists.

Comment: @Suamere, there are definitely plenty of people who want to *always* do thing the web services way, and just think the extra effort is the price of doing things "professionally". I tend to disagree with these people about more than just this! I think it's a question of philosophy, e.g. how important it is to set up the team for success vs. how important it is to adopt "best practices" and such from external experts.